# Use of Gstreamer RTSP server with Android

Tags: android, gstreamer

I have an android application that is able to open an UDP socket, connect to server, receive data (h264 flow), decode the data received and display it on the smartphone screen.

What I am trying to do now is to replace my server with the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=toystory.h264  ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=nal ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=x.x.x.x port=5000
```

When I launch the android I get nothing on the screen (No data received by the client, no connection established between client and server).

To open the socket, I am using the following java code:

```
 try 
{ 
IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(dstAddress); 
socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT); 
socket.connect(IPAddress,PORT); 
sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, IPAddress, PORT); 
if (socket.isConnected()) { 
                socket.send(sendPacket); 
            } 
receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffr, buffr.length, IPAddress, PORT); 
socket.receive(receivePacket); 
} 
catch(IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

Could you please guide me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For rtsp server on Androud you should use gstreamer rtsp lib.

In short:

on server side use this pipeline:

`filesrc location=toystory.h264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96`

use it in rtsp server "wrapper" code. (check it in repo).

for client use this pipeline:

`rtspsrc location=rtsp://host_address:host_port/host_mount ! "
                                              "rtpjitterbuffer ! "
                                              "rtph264depay ! "
                                              "h264parse ! "
                                              "avdec_h264 ! "
                                              "autovideosink`

You can look at this repos for example.

https://github.com/tamashevich-valery/rtsp-server

https://github.com/tamashevich-valery/rtsp-client